# Why is my command line showing error in my javascript language

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have an error with my discord bot,
OS: Windows 10
language: node.js, javascript where is the error?
I am new baby in programming in javascript
main.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();



  client.once('ready', () => {
          client.channels.get('code-channel').send('Hello here!');
});



    client.login('code-for-login');
});
```

cmd

```
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Projekty\Dis. bot>node .
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Projekty\Dis. bot\main.js:8
          client.channels.get('792759306831265825').send('Hello here!');
                          ^

TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Projekty\Dis. bot\main.js:8:27)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:482:28)
    at Client.emit (node:events:388:22)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Projekty\Dis. bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:431:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Projekty\Dis. bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:415:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Projekty\Dis. bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:197:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Projekty\Dis. bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:475:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Projekty\Dis. bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:447:16)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Projekty\Dis. bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Discord.js v12, you need to `.fetch` a `Guild`, `Channel`, `GuildMember` and `Role` to access it or you can use `.cache.get`.

> v12 introduces the concept of managers, you will no longer be able to directly use collection methods such as Collection#get on data structures like Client#users. You will now have to directly ask for cache on a manager before trying to use collection methods. Any method that is called directly on a manager will call the API, such as GuildMemberManager#fetch and MessageManager#delete.

Accessing from cache: `client.guilds.cache.get("ID")`, `Guild.members.cache.get("ID")`, `Guild.roles.cache.get("ID")`

Fetching: `await client.guilds.fetch("ID")`, `await Guild.members.fetch("ID")`, `await Guild.roles.fetch("ID")`

What you are looking for: `client.channels.cache.get("ID")`. Of course, you can use `.fetch`: `await client.channels.fetch("ID")`

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

// You need to make the function 'async' if you are using 'await'
client.once('ready', async () => {
  client.channels.cache.get('code-channel').send('Hello here!');

  // You can use the both

  (await client.channels.fetch('code-channel')).send('Hello here!');
  // '.fetch' returns a Promise, so you need to use 'await'
});

client.login('code-for-login');
```

A documentation that can help you: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html